# Understanding weight and layout_weight, the bigger layout_weight is, more it shrinks in the layout.

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am trying to understand the weight layout with this example.

It is definitely not a rocket science. However, this example making it...

- The weightSum dictate how big the size is and
- Then divide the layout based on layout_weight value for the view in LinearLayout.

In this example I have a layout, weighted with 5, that is then divided between two views:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/transactionRowBackground"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Test Title"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subHeadingTextSize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="This is a test description"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normalTextSize" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:contentDescription="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The thing that I cannot understand is the bigger number I give to ImageViewer the smallest space it get from the parent. So how it is actually calculating the size for ImageView.

You can try with the above xml. If you change the layout weight of an ImageView to 1 , and child linearlayout to 4, that I believe makes more sense, then the opposite will occur.

ImageView will expend and child linearlayout will shrink. I thought the bigger the number is more you get some space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since on your outermost layout you have `android:orientation="horizontal"`, I believe you want to vary the size/space taken by `ImageView` and internal `LinearLayout` in horizontal direction. For this case try using

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

on the layouts where you've put `android:layout_weight`. If your orientation of the outer layout was vertical, I would have used `android:layout_height="0dp"` in order for the weights to handle width/height of the layouts.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/transactionRowBackground"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Test Title"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subHeadingTextSize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="This is a test description"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normalTextSize" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:contentDescription="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Reading over Android docs might help: [Layout Weights](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

Comment: Thanks I forget the rule that once you have a weight you must set width as 0dp. Otherwise, the weight has been ignored.

Answer (score 1):

With `layout_weight` you can specify a size ratio between multiple views. E.g. you have a `MapView` and a table which should show some additional information to the map. The map should use 3/4 of the screen and table should use 1/4 of the screen. Then you will set the layout_weight of the map to 3 and the `layout_weight` of the table to 1.

To get it work you also have to set the height or width (depending on your orientation) to `0dp`.
**Example**

If there are three text boxes and two of them declare a weight of 1, while the third one is given no weight (0), then remaining space is assigned as follows:

> 1st text box = 1/(1+1+0)
>
> 2nd text box = 1/(1+1+0)
>
> 3rd text box = 0/(1+1+0)